# can we call super() when my class inherited from interface?what will happen?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Suppose, if my class inherited from an interface, can `super()` be used in method of the class? An interface has no concrete method. How can `super()` be used? What will happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot inherit from an interface in Java. Your class will be inherited from Object. And so it is Object's constructor you call.

Answer (score 5):

Any class will inherit from `java.lang.Object` so this will be the `super` in your case.

Answer (score 5):

the constructor for the `Object` class will be called :)

Answer (score 1):

a class cannot inherit from interface - inheritance from interface is allawed only by another interface. so in that case there's no use for the super() method (since there's no implementation).